# Can't create cmake rules for compile SFML project

Tags: c++, cmake, sfml

I have **build/CMakeLists.txt** file:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
project(Tetris)

include_directories(
    "headers"
)

set(SFML_DEPENDENCIES)
set(SFML_DEPENDENCIES ${SFML_SYSTEM_DEPENDENCIES} ${SFML_DEPENDENCIES})
set(SFML_DEPENDENCIES ${SFML_GRAPHICS_DEPENDENCIES} ${SFML_DEPENDENCIES})
set(SFML_DEPENDENCIES ${SFML_WINDOW_DEPENDENCIES} ${SFML_DEPENDENCIES})

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/g++-5)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -Wall -g")

set(EXECUTABLE_NAME "tetris")
file(GLOB SOURCES *.cpp)
add_executable(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
```

When I run **cmake .. && make** I have a screen of messages saying I did not include SFML library:

```
undefined reference to `sf::VertexArray::operator[](unsigned long)'
undefined reference to `sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key)'
```

and so on. I also tried to include flags to CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS variable: 
**-lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system** it doesn't work either. But if I run g++ from the console directly all compiles just fine:

```
g++-5 --std=c++11 -Wall main.cpp Game.cpp Window.cpp Board.cpp -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
```

I use Linux Mint if it has any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the location of SFML package, and add include directories and link.

In your CMakeLists.txt:
Change this line:

```
target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
```

By:

```
# Detect and add SFML
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
#Find any version 2.X of SFML
#See the FindSFML.cmake file for additional details and instructions
find_package(SFML 2 REQUIRED system window graphics)
if(SFML_FOUND)
  include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})
  target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

[Source](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/wiki/Tutorial%3A-Build-your-SFML-project-with-CMake)

**EDITED**:

For SFML v1, change `find_package` line by:

```
find_package(SFML 1 REQUIRED system window graphics)
```

Comment: Edited, BTW have you instaled properly SFML?

Comment: You are right. I did not install it properly, it's a nightmare to me for about four hours. I created a cmake_modules/FindSFML.cmake file as you pointed out but it says I have SFML v1 installed, but I compile SFML 2.4 from sources and all finished fine. How on the earth g++ compile it properly in this way.

Comment: @JamesMay Edited, please chage `find_package` to use v1 of SFML

Comment: BTW, if you compiled SFML from source, do forget to do `make install` as sudo o root user